ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "eladqw",
    password: "******",
    port:3306,
    options: {
        encrypt: false
    }
});
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");

});

I get this error its look like the first connection to mysql dosn't work
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',errno: 1251,sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
  sqlState: '08004',
  fatal: true
}

I have no idea what the problem

The error occurs because the MySQL server is configured to use the caching_sha2_password authentication plugin, which is not supported by the MySQL client version you're using in your Node.js application. By default, newer MySQL versions (8.0 and above) use caching_sha2_password.
Upgrade the mysql package to mysql2, which supports the caching_sha2_password plugin.
npm install mysql2
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "eladqw",
    password: "******",
    port: 3306
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});

